# Regex exact match with special characters

Tags: regex, search, special-characters

Lets say I have three records:

```
1. Test()
2. Test ()
3. Test
```

Right now I am having an issue where 'Test()' is returning both 'Test' and 'Test()' when it should just return 'Test()'

My regex is as simple as: `/Test()/i`

It looks like it is not reading the special characters properly. How can I go about fixing this regex?

Comment: `()` are special characters in regex. You need to escape them `\(` and `\)`

Comment: Use `/Test\(\)/i`....